# error for click events

Tags: .net

i am getting an error

Line 31:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="company" runat="server"  OnClick="company_Click">Companies
Management</asp:LinkButton><br />
```

that 'ASP.default_master' does not contain a definition for 'company_Click'
whereas the code i have written is with the ID companies as

```
   protected void companies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Redirect("Companies.aspx");
   }
```

THe ID company was for a link button that i deleted. i put a new link button with id as companies and wrote this code but i still get the old error. how do i rectify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you still have a control that have a event handler associated to the old 'company_Click'.

Try searching for 'company_Click' in all your solution to get rid of it.